# Entire function and boundedness

Tags: complex-analysis, holomorphic-functions, entire-functions

I've read a proposition that

> If $f$ is entire and Im$(f(z))\gt0$ for $z \in \mathbb C$, then $f$ has to be a constant.

I am wondering why it is true. And what does Im$(f(z))\gt0$ imply? Does that mean $f(z)$ is a constant and thus $f$ is a constant?

Comment: Are you sure that Im$f(z) >0$ only for $z \in \mathbb R$ or you want $z \in \mathbb C$ ?

Comment: Sry I made a mistake..

Comment: Why do you repeat the question in the 3rd and 4th sentences?

Comment: No I meant does $Im(f(z))\gt0$ mean $f(z)$ is a constant

Comment: Yes, but you asked it twice!

Comment: Okay, my bad, but why the down vote?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** Consider the entire function $g(z)=e^{i f(z)}$ and use the [Liouville's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville%27s_theorem_(complex_analysis))

Comment: But that is just one scenario and the entire function can be in the other form?

Comment: @J.doe $f(x)$ is an arbitrary entire function such that $\text{Im}(f(z))>0$ for all $z\in\mathbb C$.  Given the function $f$, we can always form a new entire function $g(z)$ by setting $g(z)=e^{if(z)}$.  Now show that $g(z)$ satisfies the hypotheses of Liouville's theorem and deduce that $f$ must be a constant.

Comment: This is actually very smart! How did you even come up with this idea in the first place?

Comment: Dear @J.doe: This idea is quite natural whenever one wants to show that the function is constant.For instance suppose instead of Im$(f)>0$ one has the condition that Re$(f)>0$ can you see what may be a suitable function in this case?

Comment: We set up a new entire function that $g(z)=e^{f(z)}$?

Comment: @J.doe Absolutely,bravo! Also its worth knowing that there is a hard theorem by Picard which says that the image of any entire function is either the whole complex plane or punctured complex plane i.e. image of entire function can miss at most one point from complex plane.

Comment: @ArpitKansal I have another question, can I ask you here? Or do you prefer me to ask another question?

Comment: @J.doe: if its not related to this question then ask it as another question!

Comment: @ArpitKansal Okay! Thank you very much!

Comment: @J.doe You're welcome.

Answer (score 0):

The imagenary part of $f$ is [harmonic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_function). If it is also positive, you can apply [Harnack's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harnack%27s_inequality) to it on larger and larger balls, and then take the radius to infinity to see that it is constant.

Comment: We haven't learned the Harnack's inequality. Can we use Liouville's theorem to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Of course not: Consider $i(1+z^2).$

Comment: Sry I made a mistake, z is supposed to be a complex number.